# Cant plot fourier series in mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, fft, series

Hi i have been trying to plot this on mathematica 8 from where x goes from -1 to 1:

```
1/2 (-1 + E^2) + 
 4 E^2 (-((2 Cos \[Pi] x)/(4 + \[Pi]^2)) - (6 Cos \[Pi] x)/(
    4 + 9 \[Pi]^2) - (10 Cos \[Pi] x)/(4 + 25 \[Pi]^2) - (
    14 Cos \[Pi] x)/(4 + 49 \[Pi]^2) - (18 Cos \[Pi] x)/(
    4 + 81 \[Pi]^2) - (22 Cos \[Pi] x)/(4 + 121 \[Pi]^2) - (
    26 Cos \[Pi] x)/(4 + 169 \[Pi]^2) - (30 Cos \[Pi] x)/(
    4 + 225 \[Pi]^2) - (34 Cos \[Pi] x)/(4 + 289 \[Pi]^2) - (
    38 Cos \[Pi] x)/(4 + 361 \[Pi]^2) - (42 Cos \[Pi] x)/(
    4 + 441 \[Pi]^2) - (46 Cos \[Pi] x)/(4 + 529 \[Pi]^2) - (
    50 Cos \[Pi] x)/(4 + 625 \[Pi]^2) - (54 Cos \[Pi] x)/(
    4 + 729 \[Pi]^2) - (58 Cos \[Pi] x)/(4 + 841 \[Pi]^2))
```

The problem is that i always get an empty graph no matter what ,i have tried using the match assistant,the functions as they are described in mathematica like instead of using the sum symbol on the assistant a write Sum[(Cos (n*Pi*x)) (((-1) ^(n) - 1)/(4 + n^(2)*Pi^(2))), {n, 0, 30}] for the first 30 sums,also insted of using ESC:P:ESC i write Pi,because i thought that Plot[] only works with native symbols but i still get a blank plot.
Has somebody had this problem before?

Thess are some alternatives i've tried with no success:

```
    S1 = Sum[(Cos (n*Pi*x)) (((-1) ^(n) - 1)/(4 + n^(2)*Pi^(2))), {n, 0, 
   30}]
SC = E^(2)*4
A0 = (1/2)*(E^(2) - 1)
FCS = A0 + (SC) (S1)
Plot[FCS,{x,-1,1}]
f = FullSimplify[FCS]
Plot[f, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: mathematica function such as Cos use square bracket around tneir arguments.

Comment: oh haha thanks wow sometimes i think mathematica isnt made for programmers i mean you can code something to get some great results but this is just pointless it solved my problem thanks.

Comment: FYI wolfram alpha allows somewhat more free form entry, but even that will take `Cos Pi x` as `(Cos(Pi))*x`. Also for single argument functions in mathematica you can alternately use the `Apply` notation, `Cos@(n Pi x)`